# Custom Search Element V1 doesn't work: how can i change to V2?

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, google-api, google-custom-search

Before `Custom Search Element V1` google worked but now when i try to search something on my website notice me that:

**Unauthorized access to internal API. Please refer to https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542055**

I think the problem is that there's an new Api version...

The code V1 was this:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata);
google.load('search', '1'); 


function googlata(){

var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('ID CSE'); 
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(20);       
customSearchControl.setLinkTarget(google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_SELF);    

var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();  
options.setAutoComplete(true);  
options.enableSearchResultsOnly();  
customSearchControl.draw('cse',options);    // 'cse' is a div for serp results

customSearchControl.execute('keyword');
```

In head this resource and then in body the div for results:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="cse"></div>
```

Now how can i change to V2 ?

Could work this code ?

```
function gcseCallback() {
    if (document.readyState != 'complete')
     return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);
  google.search.cse.element.render({
  div:'cse', 
  tag:'searchresults-only', 
  attributes:{
         resultSetSize: 20,
         noResultsString: "<div style='padding:10px'>Nothing</div>"
    }
  });
  var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('gsearch');

  element.execute('keyword');
};

window.__gcse = {
 parsetags: 'explicit',
 callback: gcseCallback
};

(function() {
 var cx = 'ID CSE';
 var gcse = document.createElement('script');
 gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
 gcse.async = true;
 gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

and only

```
<div id="cse"></div>
```

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english